# How to Update column data by doing a SUM of values from a second table depending of ID from a third one?

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables as follow (can see in attachment too)

> product_attribute_shop

```
+----------------------+--------+------------+
| id_product_attribute | price  | id_product |
+----------------------+--------+------------+
| 27934                | 50.000 | 9779       |
+----------------------+--------+------------+
| 27935                | 24.000 | 9780       |
+----------------------+--------+------------+
```

> attribute_impact

```
+------------+--------------+--------+
| id_product | id_attribute | price  |
+------------+--------------+--------+
| 9779       | 45           | 00.000 |
+------------+--------------+--------+
| 9779       | 46           | 00.000 |
+------------+--------------+--------+
| 9779       | 47           | 00.000 |
+------------+--------------+--------+
| 9779       | 55           | 00.000 |
+------------+--------------+--------+
| 9779       | 56           | 46.000 |
+------------+--------------+--------+
| 9779       | 57           | 67.000 |
+------------+--------------+--------+
```

> product_attribute_combination

```
+--------------+----------------------+
| id_attribute | id_product_attribute |
+--------------+----------------------+
| 46           | 27934                |
+--------------+----------------------+
| 56           | 27934                |
+--------------+----------------------+
| 46           | 27935                |
+--------------+----------------------+
| 57           | 27935                |
+--------------+----------------------+
```

How can I update the price of table `product_attribute_shop`.
For each `id_product_attribute` the price should be equal to the sum of price attributes from table `attribute_impact` when this attributes share the same `id_product_attribute` ?

Edit:

Here are an exemple of my 3 tables :

[product_attribute_combination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSUmp.png)

[attribute_impact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnpns.png)

[product_attribute_shop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vKQG.png)

I want to update the price of product_attribute_shop where id_product_attribute = 27934. For this i need to get the matching attributes in product_attribute_combination (looking for the same id_product_attribute) and then make the sum of the price of this attributes from table attribute_impact.

In product_attribute_shop where id_product_attribute = 27934, the price should be (46.0 + 0.00) = 46.0 instead of 50.00.

> ANSWER : To edit all combinations price, I used the following query :

```
UPDATE product_attribute_shop
SET product_attribute_shop.price =
(
   SELECT SUM(attribute_impact.price)
   FROM attribute_impact
   WHERE product_attribute_shop.id_product = attribute_impact.id_product
         AND attribute_impact.id_attribute IN
         (
            SELECT product_attribute_combination.id_attribute
            FROM product_attribute_combination
            WHERE product_attribute_combination.id_product_attribute =
                  product_attribute_shop.id_product_attribute
         )
);
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample  and the expected  result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested query to achieve what you want.

You could use a query like this if you want to update an individual product

```
update product_attribute_shop set price = (select sum(price) from attribute_impact where id_attribute in (select id_attribute from product_attribute_combination where id_product_attribute = 27934)) where id_product_attribute = 27934;
```

More note: In the attribute_impact table, the id_product is duplicate information which could easily be fetched with a join from the table product_attribute_shop. You could probably remove if not needed for any other special purpose.

Comment: Hi, this works well for the id_product_attribute(27934) exemple, but how can I achieve this for all other id_product_attribute rows without executing this query for each id_product_attribute ?

Comment: I tryed the following query 
`UPDATE product_attribute_shop
SET product_attribute_shop.price = (SELECT SUM(attribute_impact.price) FROM attribute_impact WHERE product_attribute_shop.id_product = attribute_impact.id_product AND attribute_impact.id_attribute IN (SELECT product_attribute_combination.id_attribute FROM product_attribute_combination WHERE product_attribute_combination.id_product_attribute = product_attribute_shop.id_product_attribute));`
but i got an error :
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

Comment: You can use something like this.
`update pa set pa.price = temp.total_price from product_attribute pa inner join (select sum(price) as total_price from attribute_impact ai inner join product_attribute_combination pac on ai.id_attribute = pac.id_attribute group by id_product_attribute) as temp on pa.id_product_attribute = temp.id_product_attribute;`
The idea is to create a temporary table grouped by id_product_attribute and setting them in one query using a join.

Comment: Hi the following query worked for me :
`UPDATE product_attribute_shop
SET product_attribute_shop.price =
(
   SELECT SUM(attribute_impact.price)
   FROM attribute_impact
   WHERE product_attribute_shop.id_product = attribute_impact.id_product
         AND attribute_impact.id_attribute IN
         (
            SELECT product_attribute_combination.id_attribute
            FROM product_attribute_combination
            WHERE product_attribute_combination.id_product_attribute =
                  product_attribute_shop.id_product_attribute
         )
);`